# Redefine chapter title appearance with arsclassica

Tags: chapters, classicthesis

```
\newcommand\Chapter[2]{
  \chapter[#1: {\itshape#2}]{#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}
}
```

don't function

for a result like this:

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,%                      % corpo del font principale
               a4paper,%                   % carta A4
               twoside,openright,%         % fronte-retro
%              oneside,openany,%           % solo fronte
               titlepage,%                 % frontespizio
               headinclude,,footinclude,%  % testatina e piede di pagina
               BCOR5mm,%                   % rilegatura di 5 mm
               cleardoublepage=empty,%     % pagine vuote senza testatina e piede di pagina
               tablecaptionabove,%         % didascalie in cima alle tabelle
               ]{scrreprt}                 % classe report di KOMA-Script;



%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                   % codifica dei font:
                                           % NOTA BENE! richiede una distribuzione *completa* di LaTeX,
                                           % per esempio TeXLive o MiKTeX *complete*

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                % codifica di input; anche [latin1] va bene
                                           % NOTA BENE! va accordata con le preferenze dell'editor

%\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}        % per scrivere in italiano e in inglese;
                                           % l'ultima lingua (l'italiano) risulta predefinita
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}         

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}                   % rientra il primo capoverso di ogni sezione

\usepackage{graphicx}                      % immagini

\usepackage{listings}                      % codici

\usepackage[font=small]{quoting}           % citazioni

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}        % matematica

\usepackage[italian]{varioref}             % riferimenti completi della pagina

\usepackage{mparhack,fixltx2e,relsize}     % finezze tipografiche

\usepackage{tabularx}                      % tabelle di larghezza prefissata

\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,backref,square,natbib,backend=biber]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{Bibliografia.bib}          % database di biblatex 

\usepackage{subfig}                        % sottofigure, sottotabelle

\usepackage{lipsum}                        % testo fittizio

\usepackage{eurosym}                       % simbolo dell'euro

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,%          % numeri dei capitoli nel font Euler
            subfig,%                       % se si usa il pacchetto subfig
            beramono,%                     % Bera Mono come font a spaziatura fissa
            eulermath,%                    % AMS Euler come font per la matematica
            pdfspacing,%                   % migliora il riempimento di riga
            listings,%                     % codici
%           parts,%                        % da decommentare in un documento diviso in parti
            ]{classicthesis}               % stile ClassicThesis

\usepackage{arsclassica}                   % modifica alcuni aspetti di ClassicThesis

\renewcommand\formatchapter[1]{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\chapterNumber\thechapter\hspace{10pt}\vline\ }%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd0\relax}%
    \raggedright\spacedallcaps{#1}%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\usepackage{bookmark}                      % segnalibri

\input{impostazioni-tesi}                  % file con le impostazioni personali

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\pagenumbering{roman}

\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Frontespizio}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Colophon}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Dedica}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Indici}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Sommario+Abstract}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Ringraziamenti}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Introduzione}
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Capitoli/Lorem}
\input{Capitoli/Ipsum}
\input{Capitoli/Commento}
\input{Capitoli/Rapporto}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Bibliografia}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Dichiarazione}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `arsclassica`  defines a style that reproduces the looks of a very special book. Changing that would violate its purpose. The  current implementation of ` arsclassica` does not allow for your change and would need re-implementation.

Comment: Can you extend your question? Add a real question perhaps? What is it, you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to achieve what  is shown in the picture or is this the current non-working state? I twould be really nice if you can add a minimal working example to show us what is going on. Please also add, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please give the OP time to react, before Close-Voting or Low-Quality-issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{classicthesis,arsclassica}

\newcommand*{\Chapter}[2]{%
    \chapter[#1: \textit{#2}]{#1}%
    \begingroup
    \raggedright\Large\itshape
    #2\par
    \endgroup
    \nobreak\vspace{\glueexpr \bigskipamount*3 \relax}%
    % Adjust this factor as needed ..........^
}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Chapter{Il titolo}{E il sottotitolo}

Testo.

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Output produced]

**Edit:**
You might also want to consider

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{classicthesis,arsclassica}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\Chapter}[2]{%
    \chapter[#1: \textit{#2}]{#1}%
    \vspace{-\bigskipamount}%
    \begingroup
    \raggedright\Large\itshape
    #2\par
    \endgroup
    \nobreak\vspace{\glueexpr \bigskipamount*3 \relax}%
    % Adjust this factor as needed ..........^
}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Chapter{Il titolo}{E il sottotitolo}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

with reduced vertical spacing between title and subtitle.

Comment: `\vspace{3\bigskipamount}` is as good.

Comment: @egreg, I'm surprised of you!  Don’t you mind the stretch and shrink components?

Comment: Not for a chapter heading. The spacing parameters for them should be rigid.

Comment: @egreg: You're probably right (as you always are ;-)  Edit: of course, you don't need my permission to edit my answer.

Comment: I am truly grateful to you for the help

Comment: This was just the first idea that popped into my mind: better solutions are possible, by tweaking a little the internal macros of the _arsclassica_ package, but this would require a precise specification of the output you want to obtain.  Besides, I think that the authors of _classicthesis_ and of _arsclassica_ will not be very pleased… :-)